# Associate scatter plot data with per-item labels

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data in a Google Sheets table, formatted like so:

```
Label | ValueA | ValueB
------+--------+-------
A     |      1 |     1
B     |      1 |     2
A     |      3 |     3
B     |      2 |     4
C     |      9 |     1
```

I would like to render a scatterplot, with a single colored point for each entry, in which everything with an A label is color 1, everything with a B label is color 2, and so on, and they all share the same coordinate space.

I've poked around quite a bit in the options available in the UI, but nothing seems to do it. Multi color plots can be made, but they never associate the labels the way I want them to.

I guess this will take some scripting to do, but I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a bubble chart instead?:

[image: SO32971458 first example]

I suspect what you really want may be:

[image: SO32971458 second example]

but the logic of the data layout that seems to be required to achieve this escapes me.

Comment: I tried the bubble chart type, and it sort of works, but the dataset has several hundred closely packed points, and we want to compare trends between different labels, so the bubbles end up being very clumsy for that as they are very large... I just reread the doc for the bubbles though and I noticed that you can include a size parameter. I will give that a try.